# Translating UIScroll and UIPageControl from Objective C to swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

How would you write this in swift? I'm having trouble translating this because swift is my first language and this is all written in Objective C.

```
UIScrollView * scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 3, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    UIPageControl * pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 90, scrollView.frame.size.width, 20)];
    pageControl.numberOfPages = scrollView.contentSize.width/scrollView.frame.size.width;
    [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

Then you need to add the following two methods:

- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {
    CGFloat x = pageControl.currentPage * scrollView.frame.size.width;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, 0) animated:YES];
}

-(void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  {
    NSInteger pageNumber = roundf(scrollView.contentOffset.x / (scrollView.frame.size.width));
    pageControl.currentPage = pageNumber;
```

Comment: How much do you understand swift? which parts are you struggling on?

Comment: Well I know enough to know that I want to connect my UIScrollView with my PageController and this has the resources I need but I'm getting errors on calling the function for the pageController. Say for instance I have func changePage(sender: UIPageControl){ pageControl.currentPage - has an error stating that there isnt a pageControl.currentPage available }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First things first - I strongly encourage you to read the resources on Swift and Objective-C interoperability. See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/ for more details.

Swift is a language with it's own idioms. Objective-C code can be translated into them in various ways. For example, you must use pointers when working with objects in Objective-C, which implicitly makes it possible to have a `nil` reference. Swift uses optional types to express that, so `UIScrollView * scrollView` could be translated into `let scrollView : UIScrollView` or `let scrollView : UIScrollView?`, depending on context.

Of course, this is just a tip of an iceberg. The possible changes in translation depending on context go a log way, so it way better to learn and understand basic Swift before you start to migrate your code.

Ok, since we're clear now, here comes the translation:

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 3, scrollView.frame.size.height)
scrollView.delegate = self
let pageControl = UIPageControl(frame:CGRectMake(0, 90, scrollView.frame.size.width, 20))
pageControl.numberOfPages = Int(scrollView.contentSize.width / scrollView.frame.size.width)
pageControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("changePage:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)


func changePage(sender: AnyObject) -> () {
    let x = CGFloat(pageControl.currentPage) * scrollView.frame.size.width
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(x, 0), animated: true)
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> () {
    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width);
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}
```